# SQL Unable to Convert/Cast, Plus Precision Issues

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is my syntax. Im trying to only return the rows where `assg.Hours_Act <> Sum(assh.HourEntry)` for a specific callID's HeatSeq.

In my having statement below you can see how I am attempting this, but no conversion that I've tried thus far has worked.

```
SELECT assg.CallID, assg.HEATSeq, assg.Hours_Act, SUM(assh.HourEntry) AS HourSum
FROM Heat.Dbo.asgnmnt AS assg
INNER JOIN heat.dbo.Assignment_Hours AS assh
ON assg.CallID = assh.CallID AND assg.HEATSeq = assh.HEATSeq
WHERE assg.Hours_Act IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY assg.callid, assg.HEATSeq, assg.Hours_Act
HAVING assg.Hours_Act <> CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),SUM(assh.HourEntry))
```

The issue is the precision of the SUM is creating a different value than what is in `Hours_Act`.
The `assg.Hours_Act` is a `VARCHAR` and the Sum(assh.HourEntry) returns a `DECIMAL`

Below is a screenshot of my results where you can see the issue:
[image]

EDIT: Final Working code:

```
SELECT assg.CallID, assg.HEATSeq, assg.Hours_Act, SUM(assh.HourEntry) AS HourSum
FROM Heat.Dbo.asgnmnt AS assg
INNER JOIN heat.dbo.Assignment_Hours AS assh
ON assg.CallID = assh.CallID AND assg.HEATSeq = assh.HEATSeq
WHERE assg.Hours_Act IS NOT NULL AND ISNUMERIC(assg.Hours_Act) = 1
GROUP BY assg.callid, assg.HEATSeq, assg.Hours_Act
HAVING CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2), assg.Hours_Act) <> CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2), SUM(assh.HourEntry))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@antisanity is correct.  You can also try filtering out any rows where the assg.Hours_Act is not a numeric value.  If you have any bad data stored, this could be causing the conversion issue.  Just add to your WHERE clause:

```
AND ISNUMERIC(assg.Hours_Act) = 1
```

Alternately, you could just select on the source data where ISNUMERIC = 0 to see if you have any bad data that needs cleaned.

Comment: This was the ticket, I must have had some junk data in there which was bombing my convert... As you can see from my script I already tried to account for this with the NOT NULL in my where clause but yours cleared it up completely for me! A combined effort really because @antisanity is partially right as well, the converts are needed once the data is for sure a numeric. THNK you to both of you!

Answer (score 1):

Try casting your varchar value, `assg.Hours_Act`, to a decimal instead.

```
cast(assg.Hours_Act as decimal(10,2)) <> sum(assh.HourEntry)
```

If you've got blanks then you might try:

```
cast(assg.Hours_Act as float) <> sum(assh.HourEntry)
```

Comment: Is it possible to do so in the SELECT statement and alias the value?I've tried this exact syntax, plus i've tried doing a CONVERT to decimal as well and I get an error that says `Error converting data type varchar to numeric.` every time.

Comment: Depends on what data you have in there. You could try casting to `float` instead. It's more forgiving with `varchar` conversion so far as I've seen.

Comment: Thank you for the help antisantiy! Dave's answer cleared up the root issue I was having but I gave ya a big +1 because this is what I too was trying and was still getting the Error converting. It was really a combined effort here! thank you!